# How do I constrain a value to audio frequency in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

If I wanted to make my own audio visualiser of sorts, for example have an image of something expand and contract with the beat of an audio, how would I do this? Is there any way of getting the audio frequency in ffmpeg and constraining it to some other value? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is some indication of sample loudness. For digital signals, this can be measured via the RMS level. You can use the [`astats` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#astats-1) in ffmpeg with metadata injection to get that RMS level per sample:

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4a -filter:a "astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=mode=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level:file=stats.txt" -f null -
```

Here, `metadata=1` and `reset=1` enable outputting of metadata, and the [`ametadata`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#metadata_002c-ametadata) filter prints those values (`mode=print`). The output is written to `stats.txt` while no actual encoding is performed (`-f null -`). The log looks like this:

```
frame:0    pts:0       pts_time:0      
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-77.999541
frame:1    pts:1536    pts_time:0.032  
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-68.693275
frame:2    pts:3072    pts_time:0.064  
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-62.974396
frame:3    pts:4608    pts_time:0.096  
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-61.259331
frame:4    pts:6144    pts_time:0.128
```

You can filter the lines based on the `lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level` key and use those dB values for visualization:

```
grep "lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=" stats.txt | sed 's/lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=//g' > stats_clean.txt
```

The minumum is minus infinity, and the maximum is 0 – so you have to appropriately rescale those values yourself. You may have to filter these values based on some moving average filter to get a proper visualization.

PS: With music, there is no *single* audio frequency. The audio you're hearing is composed of different frequencies, which we call a *spectrum*. It looks like this, where you see the intensity of certain frequency over time:

[image: By Aquegg - Own work, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=5544473]

ffmpeg's `astats` filter can only output information in the time domain, not the frequency domain (as the above image shows). If you want to generate a spectrum with ffmpeg, you can do it with the [`showspectrum` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#showspectrum-1) though.

Comment: thanks for the response! Do you have any idea how I would actually do the constraining bit? Maybe an image of a circle pump to the amplitude or something?

Comment: For me, “constraining” means just scaling (perhaps logarithmically?) the dBFS values from `[-∞, 0]` to `[0, 100]`. The practical implementation of that depends on what you're using to actually display the visualization (a C program? Python?), and what visualization type you have chosen (e.g., a simple “fader” bar?). Can't give you a more specific example there.

Comment: no, I want the visualisation in the actual video. Is there no ffmpeg command to 'map' the dBFS value to the width of an -i image.png or -i video.mov for example?

Comment: This wasn't so clear from your question. You can use the [`showvolume`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#showvolume) filter and export that, but it's not that customizable. `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex showvolume output.mp4` for example.